# Javascript - Webpage contents to String

Tags: javascript, html, string, http, xmlhttprequest

I'm currently playing around with JavaScript attempting to fetch the contents of a webpage as plain text, and dump the text to a String.

I have found many ways to do this but nothing seems to happen when I do something similar to this: (In this example I use a plain text file)

```
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else { // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
}
    // As you can see I'm also spamming myself with alerts, but they also
    // just return blank.
    alert(xmlhttp.response);
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/examples/UTF-8-demo.txt", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

**How do I go about doing this?**

Comment: Just a word of advice - use `console.log` for debugging as opposed to `alert`.

Comment: @JonathanBrooks Thanks for the reply. I was only using `alert()` because I was impatiently looking to see what was happening on execution. (I'm using Brackets)

Comment: Are you running this code on the same domain as the `XMLHttpRequest`? Otherwise it's most likely due to a same origin policy error

Comment: @JonathanBrooks Yes. Thanks, the answer also states that, I believe thats the error at hand.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot because of the Same-Origin-Policy.. otherwise each webpage could load some bank website or so.. So they (Browser vendors) implemented Same-Origin Policy.. You can access only websites which have give you access to..

just try put this in you console on stackoverflow:

1. open devtools while you see this site
2. put this into the console

`jQuery.get('http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/examples/UTF-8-demo.txt')`

Comment: AHH jQuery! :) So what would I do when I obtain it with jQuery?

Comment: You can construct the XMLHttpRequest, like you did.. it's the same under the hood ;)

Comment: Oh gosh. I'm quite new to JS. (I'm absorbed in Java most of the time) I just added in the jQuery line, and nothing is happening (It has frozen the entire process). Am I still supposed to open the request to the website after this?

Comment: @FinnRayment No, I just executed this code in the console, while surfing on stackoverflow.. I's already using jQuery.. just open the Console and paste it there

Comment: @FinnRayment Sure, if you want to make it work in you project, add jquery in a script tag

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll see how I go. @Arjun Will try that now.

Comment: @Arjun @webdeb I just realised, it's already inside `<script>` tags as my entire program is being run inside of it. http://pastebin.com/yzPwFRrR

Comment: @FinnRayment Insert `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>` just after the `<body>` tag.

Comment: @Arjun Alright, I'm getting further now, but **how** do I implement it into the XMLHttpRequest?

Comment: @FinnRayment So as you said that you don't want to use jquery, then paste your JavaScript into the console, or if you want to use jquery, then add that line , whic is in the answer by webdeb in the browser console.   Hope it helps

Comment: @Arjun Sorry, I have no idea what you mean? I'm happy to use jQuery but have no idea how to implement it. I'm not using a console, I'm compiling it in a HTML page via. Brackets.

Comment: @FinnRayment put this in HTML somewhere:
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

Comment: Yes, I understand and did that. But nothing happens as I do this.

Comment: @FinnRayment you should first make your expectations clear, you've added jquery to your html.. nothing will happen until you do something

Comment: Ok. So I added in the jQuery text, and then added in the original code with my `XmlHTTPRequest`. I run my application, and it still returns null because of the Same-Origin Policy.